# PHP Add null to array value if it doesn't exist

Tags: php

I'm generating data arrays and want to add 0/null to a specific month, where no data is present, but been struggling with it for few days.

I'm generating the final dataset array like this

```
foreach ($patients as $key => $item) {
    $labels[] = $item['month'];
    usort($labels, "compare_months");
    $labels = array_unique($labels);

    $chartData[ $item['brand_name'] ]['data'][]     = 
    $item['patientsCount'];
    $chartData[ $item['brand_name'] ]['brand_data'] = [
        "name"  => $item['brand_name'],
        "color" => $item['color']
    ];
}

foreach ($chartData as $item) {
    $pointRadius++;

    $dataSet[] = [
        'label'           => $item['brand_data']['name'],
        'data'            => $item['data'],
        'pointRadius'     => $pointRadius,
        'fill'            => false,
        'borderWidth'     => 1,
        'backgroundColor' => "#" . $item['brand_data']['color'],
        'borderColor'     => "#" . $item['brand_data']['color'], 
    ];
}

$finalData[] = [
    'labels'   => $labels,
    'datasets' => $dataSet
];
```

Which gives me this json response

```
[
  {
    "labels":[
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July"
    ],
    "datasets":[
      {
        "label":"Medicine 1",
        "data":[
          1
        ],
        "pointRadius":1,
        "fill":false,
        "borderWidth":1,
        "backgroundColor":"#ea5f2d",
        "borderColor":"#ea5f2d"
      },
      {
        "label":"Medicine 2",
        "data":[
          1,
          1,
          1
        ],
        "pointRadius":2,
        "fill":false,
        "borderWidth":1,
        "backgroundColor":"#ffb400",
        "borderColor":"#ffb400"
      },
      {
        "label":"Medicine 3",
        "data":[
          1,
          1,
          2
        ],
        "pointRadius":3,
        "fill":false,
        "borderWidth":1,
        "backgroundColor":"#ff7777",
        "borderColor":"#ff7777"
      },
      {
        "label":"Medicine 4",
        "data":[
          1,
          1,
          2
        ],
        "pointRadius":4,
        "fill":false,
        "borderWidth":1,
        "backgroundColor":"#64a36f",
        "borderColor":"#64a36f"
      },
      {
        "label":"Medicine 5",
        "data":[
          2
        ],
        "pointRadius":5,
        "fill":false,
        "borderWidth":1,
        "backgroundColor":"#e7e6fc",
        "borderColor":"#e7e6fc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, for some items, the data object only contains 1 value which is wrong, because I need to add zeros to months, where there is no data.

Can this be done in `MySQL` or is it better to use `PHP` and how?

### EDIT 1

Here is the array I am currently getting.

```
Array
(
    [MEDICINE 1] => Array
        (
            [April] => 1
        )

    [MEDICINE 2] => Array
        (
            [April] => 1
            [July] => 2
        )

    [MEDICINE 3] => Array
        (
            [April] => 1
            [May] => 1
            [July] => 2
        )

    [MEDICINE 4] => Array
        (
            [May] => 1
            [July] => 3
        )

    [MEDICINE 5] => Array
        (
            [June] => 2
        )

    [MEDICINE 6] => Array
        (
            [July] => 1
        )

)
```

As you can see some medicines have data for only one month and I want to add these months to the medicine array with 0 value, if there is no data.

Comment: Before doing `'data' => $item['data'],` maybe just test if `count($item['data']) > 1`, if true add the array as you did, else just add 0 or null?

Comment: @MickaelLeger I tried it and it added the 0's to wrong months.

Comment: You did `$test = $item['data']; if (count($test) <= 1 { $test = 0; } ... $dataSet[] = [..., 'data' => $test, ... ]` ? And you do `$pointRadius` BEFORE adding it, this is really what you want? Most of the time the increase go at the end of the loop, just asking

Comment: whoops with the $pointRadius, but the code example doesn't add zeros for each month

Comment: The code example I gave you will add 0 only if you have 1 or less data, not if you have 2 or more. That's not what you wanted? Maybe do some `var_dump($charData)` before the foreach loop and show us the output + where you should add 0

Comment: @MickaelLeger not exactly. as you can see I have months array, where each number in data array should point to the month. if there is no data for that months, then add 0 to the array in the right location, but not replace the value

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after each `foreach`: `if (count($item['data']) < 2) continue;`. Because you need skip if length of data is smaller than 2.

```
foreach ($patients as $key => $item) {
    if (count($item['data']) < 2) continue;

    $labels[] = $item['month'];
    usort($labels, "compare_months");
    $labels = array_unique($labels);

    $chartData[ $item['brand_name'] ]['data'][]     = 
    $item['patientsCount'];
    $chartData[ $item['brand_name'] ]['brand_data'] = [
        "name"  => $item['brand_name'],
        "color" => $item['color']
    ];
}

foreach ($chartData as $item) {
    $pointRadius++;

    if (count($item['data']) < 2) continue;

    $dataSet[] = [
        'label'           => $item['brand_data']['name'],
        'data'            => $item['data'],
        'pointRadius'     => $pointRadius,
        'fill'            => false,
        'borderWidth'     => 1,
        'backgroundColor' => "#" . $item['brand_data']['color'],
        'borderColor'     => "#" . $item['brand_data']['color'], 
    ];
}

$finalData[] = [
    'labels'   => $labels,
    'datasets' => $dataSet
];
```

Comment: this does no work since it removes null values, but I need those for my chart.

Comment: you can use same method for your javascript which creates chart. :|